# Customise title in bibliography in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am rather new to LaTeX and am trying to find my way around how to customise my bibliography. I use

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=chem-angew, articletitle=true]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{file.bib}
```

The used style is pretty close to what I was hoping for, unfortunately it does not show titles for articles and thesis. I found a way around that with ar`ticletitle=true` but could not find anything similar for PhD or master thesis.
Hope you may help.

Answer (score 3):

Might be an inadvertent omission `biblatex-chem` (specifically in the file `chem-angew.bbx`), though there may be reasons why there are not supposed to be titles in theses even when that option is enabled.

However, if you add these lines to the `thesis` driver, it seems to work:

```
\iftoggle{bbx:articletitle}
  {%
    \usebibmacro{title}
      \newunit        
}
  {}%
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=chem-angew, articletitle=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:articletitle}
    {%
      \usebibmacro{title}%
      \newunit
    }
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{document}

% article, book, PhD thesis, MA thesis:
\cite{aksin, aristotle:anima, geer, loh}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```